# How to save score to SharedPreferences then update it?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have an app which shows the total earnings of stars in the MainActivity as textview. I want to do is input 0 if the app is run for the first time. Then afterwards as I finish a level and earn some stars (like currentScore + 50 = newScore) it will be redirected to MainActivity with the newScore textView.

This is my MainActivity where the the textview shows the score

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static TextView txt_stars;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updateStars();
  }

    public void updateStars() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("Stars", 0);
    editor.commit();
    txt_stars = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStars);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        //the key is "Stars" don't forget to type it as you created the Sp
    String stars = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("Stars", 0));
    txt_stars.setText(stars);
}
}
```

And for the activity where I read the current score then add 50 to it then update

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     Integer newstars = sharedPreferences.getInt("Stars", 0);
     Integer totalStars = newstars + 50;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
     editor.putInt("Stars", totalStars);
     editor.commit();

  //please help me improve my code here

    Intent nextForm = new Intent(.MainActivity");
    startActivity(nextForm);

  }
```

And also can a SharedPreferences be use in different activities? Like I just save a score from ActivityOne and can be read in ActivityTwo?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think an improvement would just be having the `sharedStars` and `editor` be members of the class, so you're not instantiating them every time the user clicks the button. You could also keep a local count of the stars so you're not reading them over and over.

Comment: Yes, SharedPreferences can be used between different activities. They can even be used between different apps *if you create a shared preferences file with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` or `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should first read [`the SharedPreferences documentation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), and then follow my steps to save values with `SharedPreferences`

Your `UpdateStars()` method should look like this :

```
public class updateStars() {
txt_stars = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStars);
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
//the key is "Stars" don't forget to type it as you created the Sp
String stars = String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("Stars", 0));
txt_stars.setText(stars);
}
```

And everytime you want to keep the users `Stars` you'll have to use the `putInt()` :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("Stars", YOUR_INT_VALUE); //Here you save the stars of the user
editor.commit();
```

Comment: it still shows zero after I play the game. I edited my codes above with the your codes.

Comment: @kcNeko you put it wrong.... You have to put the code where appears the `Editor` when you want to save the value, doesn't matter if you put it on differents class, just where you do `currentScore + 50 = newScore` add the second code of my answer.

Comment: Sorry about this, but can you show it to me? I just can't get it right.

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw my error there,  'sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());' should be 'SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());'

Comment: @kcNeko I'm glad to help you  happy coding ^^

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a useful SharedPreferences class to write/retrieve data easily, which you can be copy/pasted from here:

https://github.com/asystat/bus_locator/blob/master/benasque2014/Autobus/src/com/example/com/benasque2014/mercurio/KeyStoreController.java

Then you write like this:

```
KeyStoreController.getKeyStore().setPreference("yourKey", yourValue)
```

yourValue can be int, boolean, long or string

and to retrieve:

```
KeyStoreController.getKeyStore().getInt("yourKey", defaultValue)
KeyStoreController.getKeyStore().getLong("yourKey", defaultValue)
KeyStoreController.getKeyStore().getString("yourKey", defaultValue)
KeyStoreController.getKeyStore().getBoolean("yourKey", defaultValue)
```

You can also call KeyStoreController.getKeyStore().appOpened() in the onCreate method of your MainApplication or Launcher Activity, and then you can use getTimesOpened() and isFirstLaunch() for any feature you'd like to add to your app.

I hope it can be useful to someone.

Comment: Oh, nice class @Perroloco, didn't know about that :)